# Backpropagation neural network doesn't learn well

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I am struggling with my implementation of backpropagation learning. The only thing the network manages to learn well is OR with a 2-2-1 network. It fails to learn all other logic functions, staying at a large L2 error. Sometimes (as in my linear example) the error decreases, and then starts increasing. I've tried tweaking the learning rate, but it still didn't work.

I'm the least sure about my bias. For every layer I create a vector with the number of entries equal to the number of neurons in the next layer, and I add the sum of all these numbers (equivalent to taking the dot product with a vector of all ones), which substitutes for the bias row in the weights matrix. Then during back propagation I update it just with deltas of the next layer. Is that a correct method?

However I don't think the problem is (only) with bias, because the network also doesn't learn linear functions, such as (x+y+z)/3.

Here's my learning code:

```py
def train(self, Xtrain, ytrain, alpha, niter):
        for t in range(niter):        
            #pick one datapoint        
            i = np.random.randint(0, len(Xtrain))
            X = Xtrain[i]
            y = ytrain[i]
            #compute ypred saving outputs for all hidden layers
            results = [X] #"outputs" in the input layer, for nicer indexing
            a = X        
            for i in range(self.nlayers-1):
                a = self.g(np.dot(self.thetas[i], a) + np.sum(self.biases[i]))
                results.append(a)
            ypred = a[-1]
            deltas = [None for _ in range(self.nlayers)]
            #we compute deltas, which are errors propagated backwards        
            #deltas[0] should stay None, because we don't compute errors for inputs
            deltas[self.nlayers-1] = (y-ypred) * self.dg(ypred)
            #deltas[self.nlayers-1] = (y-ypred)
            for i in range(self.nlayers-2, 0, -1):
                deltas[i] = np.dot(self.thetas[i].T, deltas[i+1]) \
                    * self.dg(results[i])        
            #now we compute changes in weights, theta is exterior product
            #of outputs from source layer and deltas of target layer
            delta_thetas = []        
            for i in range(self.nlayers-1):
                delta_thetas.append(np.dot(deltas[i+1], results[i].T))
                #update weights by deltas * learning rate            
                self.thetas[i] += alpha * delta_thetas[i]
                self.biases[i] += alpha * deltas[i+1]
```

And the full code is here: http://pastebin.com/jbGbF0Dn

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

EDIT: I include some sample training logs, to illustrate what's wrong. Test code:

```
def testLinear():
    net = NN(3,[3,5,1])
    Xtrain = [np.random.random(size=(3,1)) for i in range(1000)]
    ytrain = [np.array(np.sum(X)/3).reshape((1,1)) for X in Xtrain]
    net.train(Xtrain, ytrain, niter=50000, alpha=0.1)
```

This is a situation when the error was nicely decreasing at first, and then started to increase more and more after a certain point.

```
Learning with alpha = 0.1
Iteration 0: L2 error [[ 28.66232059]]
Iteration 1000: L2 error [[ 27.25906508]]
...
Iteration 9000: L2 error [[ 7.32406859]]
Iteration 10000: L2 error [[ 6.25700023]]
Iteration 11000: L2 error [[ 5.45473646]]
...
Iteration 18000: L2 error [[ 4.90465238]]
...
Iteration 24000: L2 error [[ 6.24519747]]
...
Iteration 45000: L2 error [[ 17.46215826]]
Iteration 46000: L2 error [[ 18.96317493]]
Iteration 47000: L2 error [[ 20.00523661]]
Iteration 48000: L2 error [[ 21.38221063]]
Iteration 49000: L2 error [[ 22.24753724]]
Iteration 49999: L2 error [[ 22.24753724]]
```

If I try a lower number of iterations (like a few hundreds suggested), then the error doesn't get low at all.
I tried decreasing the learning rate, for example for

```
alpha = 0.01
```

the error went down to 0.4 after 150000 iterations, and then stayed there and slowly increased for the rest of the time.
For

```
alpha = 0.005
```

the error went down just to 2.6, and then started to increase.

Testing logic functions with 2-2-1 network, then regardless of the learning rate the error stays at 1 for XOR and 0.6 for AND. It converges for OR and ~OR.

Comment: You should do a bit more work yourself before asking this, and also give us more information. For example, you might need different learning rates and iterations to learn other functions. If the error decreases and then increases, you should probably reduce the number of iterations, not tweak the learning rate, because the learning rate obviously works well up to a point. Then, look into gradient checking. You have correctly realized that biases just means multiplication with a vector of all ones. So concatenate it to your `Xtrain` and don't treat the biases separately [continued].

Comment: Doing it like that reduces the chances of introducing bugs, especially if you're not sure about something. It might not be the most efficient thing, but you'll eliminate a possible source of bugs. Finally, tell us what learning rates and number of iterations you're using. What errors do you get? What accuracy do you get? Have you compared your code to any known correct implementations? Backpropagation can be hard to debug. Maybe someone will spot some bug immediately, but it's also possible you won't get any answers unless you narrow things down for us. Maybe there's no bug at all.

Comment: I see in the code you linked that you have `50000` iterations. This sounds like complete overkill for the simple data you're trying to fit. Try a few hundred. Also try adding 1-2 more hidden neurons and maybe lowering the learning rates a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will add some sample runs to the question.

Comment: Other than that, I'll try to implement gradient checking. As for decreasing the number of iterations, it doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Your logs tell you the solution. For the first one, you have "`Iteration 18000: L2 error [[ 4.90465238]]`". This means you should stop at that iteration if that's the best you're going to get (if using random numbers, it might help to save the seed so you can reproduce the run). "the error went down to 0.4 after 150000 iterations, and then stayed there and slowly increased for the rest of the time." This is even better. Stop training after that many iterations then. These numbers don't really tell much though. What is your accuracy? Stop training when you get enough accuracy.

Comment: If you think the learning is slow, try increasing the learning rate in small increments and see if it helps. Also do this with the same seed. For example, if you get good accuracy at iteration `10000` with seed `x` and learning rate `0.01`, try with the same seed and learning rate `0.02` and see if you get good accuracy at a lower iteration and so on. When you're ready, there's fancier stuff like regulariation and momentum.

Comment: Right. However, it doesn't result in a good network. A linear function should be easy to learn, and an error of this magnitude is too big, which means something must be wrong, and stopping at that minimum is not a solution. Also it seems that for a particular run (with a seed), the change of alpha doesn't make a big difference.